# how to stop the toast message after stop executing the program

Tags: android

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME="LoginPrefs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Log.i("hello", "world");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter the Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }
        }, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do? Your code makes no sense to me.

Comment: I don't think you could cancel the displayed toast

Comment: Your question is not clear. Looking at your code the problem seems not to be to stop the toast message, but to stop the scheduler thread that periodically shows a toast message. You have to understand the Activity lifecycle because to close an activity doesn't mean to stop the program.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom global object

`private Toast toast;`

Initialize it in onCreate

`toast = Toast.makeText(YOUR_CLASS_NAME.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);`

Whenever you need to show a Toast

`toast.setText("Text...");
toast.show();`

To kill all the message based on requirement onPause or onDestroy

`toast.cancel();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you don't stop the scheduler.

When you close the Activity the Application doesn't stop so the scheduler keeps running.

You can rewrite the code to stop the scheduler when activity stops and to start the scheduler when activity starts (instead of creation).

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ScheduledExecutorService mScheduler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mScheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        mScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Log.i("hello", "world");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter the Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }
        }, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mScheduler.shutdown();
        super.onStop();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Override onBackPressed() method in your activity, place this:

```
System.exit(0);
```

this is basically used to exit but this also stop the toast. try this.

Comment: User wants to to cancel the displayed toast. Your thing will not work

Comment: "this is basically used to exit but this also stop the toast." Seriously ? This is ridiculous. And what does onBackPressed has to do with anything here ?